# How to get ServletContext attribute from a java class (not servlet)

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, listener

Good evening! I have a web app with login-logout, where you can buy or sell some products. My queries are stored in a java class, called `DBManager`, which has just static methods that are called from servlets (I can't use JSP because in this project we can't use them, the professor gives us this constraint).

So here's the problem: I used to manage connection with `ServletContextListener`. In `contextInitialized` I set up connection, and in `contextDestroyed` I shutdown it. The attribute "Connection" is stored using `ServletContext.setAttribute(Connection)`.

How can i get this parameter through the java class (not servlet) `DBManager`? I must get the object using `getServletContext()` inside a servlet and than passing it as an attribute, or there's a shortcut to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening a connection in the method contextInitialized and closing it in contextDestroyed is a bad solution. Imagine that your web site has two visitors at the same time. They would now share the same database connection. If you work with transactions, you would end up with unexpected results where one visitor commits an intermediate state of a transaction executed by the other visitor. And if the connection is ever lost (maybe because the DB server is restarted), your application will fail because it does not re-establish the connection (unless you have a very smart JDBC driver).

A very expensive but safe solution would be to open a new connection for every database operation, and close it again immediately after the operation.

For a perfect solution, you would use some kind of connection pool. Whenever you need to execute a database statement (or a sequence of statements), you would borrow a connection from the pool. Once you're finished, you would return the connection to the pool. Most pool implementations take care of things like validation (check whether the connection is still "alive"), and multiple threads (different HTTP requests send by different visitors at the same time) can execute statements in parallel.

If you want to go for this solution, maybe the Commons DbUtils library is something for you: http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/

Or you check out the documentation of your Java application server or servlet engine (Tomcat?) to see what built-in DB connection pooling features it provides.

Comment: Thank you, i think this is actually the best solution. What i did is exactly what you said, opening and closing the connection on every operation that i do on database. But the professor said that we should try to keep the connection for the whole session using ServletContextListener (it's a college project).

Comment: (continue)I agree with you, that is a bad solution, for the reasons you noticed, but i must do it in this way. So i was wondering if there's a way to keep the Connection visible all over the app, so i haven't to modify all the code.

Comment: Maybe your professor wants you to override the methods "sessionCreated" and "sessionDestroyed" in the ServletContextListener interface. If you open and close your connection there, you will get individual connections per visitor/session. Not as bad as having only a single connection, but it's not much better. Imagine that your website has 1000 concurrent visitors. You would end up with 1000 open connections, if your database can handle this at all. So you have two options: 1. make your professor happy and do as he suggest or 2. implement something better and teach him something new :-)

Comment: I think i'll make happy my professor, but i'm going to keep in mind your valuable advices. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of arbitrary getting the connection, you could change your class to receive a connection. That allows you to pass any instance of connection (what happens if you need to get data from another database?).

Also, imagine that the code will be ported to desktop. With this approach you can reuse your [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) without any changes.

```
class DBManager {
  private Connection connection;

  public DBManager(Connection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
  }
  //methods that will use the connection
}
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for the answer. But i think that's a partial solution, because i should make an instance of DBManager and than start doing queries, that's almost the same of passing Connection as attribute.

Comment: It's not the same because of the flexibility that passing the connection will add for you. To not add a lot of work just for a homework, if you will stay using just one connection, you can store a instance of your DBManager and reuse it. In real apps however you will have a pool of connections, so I recommend you to read about [datasources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your `HttpServlet` `doPost` or `doGet` methods you can call `getServletContext()`.

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) sc.getAttribute("ds");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

> A servlet can bind an object attribute into the context by name. Any attribute bound into a context is available to any other servlet that is part of the same Web application.
>
> Context attributes are LOCAL to the JVM in which they were created. This prevents ServletContext attributes from being a shared memory store in a distributed container. When information needs to be shared between servlets running in a distributed environment, the information should be placed into a session, stored in a database, or set in an Enterprise JavaBeans component.

Comment: So you mean i should extend my DBManager class with HttpServlet?

Comment: No, it' not a servlet. Just get connection object. If you want reuse it with DBManager initialize it.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand, but getting it from a servlet and than passing it as attribute (or initializing the class, which has just static methods) is what i didn't want to do. I just would like to have the Connection available in a global scope, but i don't know if it's possible

Comment: You can initialize a data source via JNDI, and get a connection from it.